# Getting a negative answer after raising number to the power of x

Tags: c, integer, pow, function-definition, long-long

I have this code that returns the answer after raising a number to an nth number.

```
int getPower(int base, int x){
    int result=1;

    while (x != 0) {
        result *= base;
        --x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I tried testing out where base is 97 and x is 5. I get a result of `-2594335`. I tried changing my data type for the result to long but I'm still getting the same negative value.

Comment: `97**5` is 8,587,340,257 and it exceeds typical limit of `int` 2,147,483,647 (`2**31 - 1`). `long` may have the same size as `int`, depending on the environment. Try `long long` or `int64_t` (defined in `stdint.h`).

Comment: @MikeCAT No luck. I still get the same negative answer.

Comment: How did you "still get the same"? Did you replace *both* the return value type *and* the intermediate variable type (i.e. `int64_t getPower` and `int64_t result`)?

Comment: @iBug Yes. I changed the return type of my getPower and result. The catcher variable in my main also has a long long data type.

Comment: @rinrin Are you printing the result with the `%lld` format specifier?

Comment: OK then how did you print it? Using the correct format specifier (`%lld` for long long or `%I64d` for `int64_t` (not Windows-compatible))?

Comment: @iBug `"%" PRId64` for `int64_t`

Comment: The correct conversion specifier for `int64_t` is the string literal to which the macro `PRId64` from `<inttypes.h>` expands.

Answer (score 6):

As already it was mentioned in comments to your question an object of the type `int` can be not large enough to be able to store such values. So substitute the type `int` for the type `long long`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int getPower( int base, unsigned int x )
{
    long long int result = 1;

    while ( x-- ) result *= base;

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int x = 5;
    int base = 97;
    
    printf( "%d in the power of %u is %lld\n", base, x, getPower( base, x ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
97 in the power of 5 is 8587340257
```

Instead of this statement

```
printf( "%d in the power of %u is %lld\n", base, x, getPower( base, x ) );
```

you can write

```
long long int result = getPower( base, x );

printf( "%d in the power of %u is %lld\n", base, x, result );
```

An alternative approach is to use for example the float type `long double` instead of the integer type `long long` as the type of the calculated value.

Comment: May try  **unsigned long long int**  for extra-large values. 
Use **printf("%llu", result);**  to print the result